# Zabbix SNMP template for Fujitsu PRIMERGY server

Tags: server, snmp, zabbix, ipmi

Looking for some Zabbix template using the SNMP interface on a Fujitsu PRIMERGY server (RX200 S8). I've been trying most of the SNMP OID on the following website: https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.231

But none of it seems working fine
All I've got is a "Not supported" status at all...

I've seen somebody using the iPMI interface to achieve that, 
but it would be great if I can stick to SNMP if possible

Comment: Double checked the host with connected SNMP availability 
(Got a green light signal on SNMP)

Answer (score 0):

First, decide what is it that you want to monitor. Then try to query those OIDs with Net-SNMP commandline tools (`snmpget`, `snmpwalk`). Then you can create a template that does what you want.

As a starting point, you can also try to use the default SNMP templates that ship with Zabbix, that will work as a test whether everything else is configured correctly. Pay extra attention to authentication parameters (community or username/password).